# Error in AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to setText on a TextView, I get an error on the phone, and in the LogCat all I get is tag: androidruntime, text: at com.examp... onPostExecute (AsyncSomething.java).
Here is my pseudo code:

```
    TextView display_car_tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        display_name_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_name_tv);
.....
     setContentView(R.layout...);
}
```

I have a button that affected to the methode that does only:

```
new AsyncSomething(this,display_car_tv).execute();
```

The code of AsyncSomething:

```
private Context context;
    private TextView tv;
    public AsyncSomethin(Context context, TextView tv){
        this.context=context;
        this.tv=tv;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String...arg0){
            //some code that works
            return sb.toString();
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        this.tv.append(result);
    }
```

What do I do wrong?
How can I get more information from LogCat?

PS : sorry for not giving the entire code, but it is not relevant.

Comment: Post full stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for the -1, I can't post the full trace, and I'm sure that for 6.5 lines of code, there are some people who will be able to help me

Comment: Your logcat should always have the full stack trace if your phone is locally connected and you actually do "adb logcat" in a terminal instead of using android studio / eclipse. You're welcome to the -1. If this is a remote crash and you haven't reproduced it you're going to have to reproduce it to make sure you fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the code you posted the only mistake I can see, probably leading your app to crash for `NullPointerException`, is that you are using `findViewById` before `setContentView`. You have always to call `setContentView` before every `findViewById`s otherwise you will  not have any widgets to find

Comment: Thank you, actually it happens to me all the time to forget this. I'll finish my app in the year 2525 x), anyway, solved.